# Python3 ftplib not fetching larger binary files

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I have the following script to fetch files from a remote FTP site and download them locally:

```
for i in ftp.nlst():
  ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + i, open(local_file_path + "/" + i, "wb").write)
```

The debug information shows that the file is being fetched, and I can see it's being streamed to the local system. After some time the download will just halt and seems like it's paused...

```
get "150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'filename' (163479928 bytes).\n"
resp "150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'filename' (163479928 bytes)."
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to experiment with maxblocksize parameter? For example:

```
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + i, open(i, "wb").write, maxblocksize=1048576)
```

I'm not sure what caused your issue, but if your files are big it probably connected with buffer size on FTP server side.

Comment: Thanks i'll give this a try. btw in Python 3 it's *blocksize* instead of *maxblocksize* ;) https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/ftplib.py#l426

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed you asked about python 3 :) I tried to reproduce your issue on my test ftp server (I use pure-ftpd) and used python 3 but everything just worked..

Answer (score 1):

If your are retrieving multiple files, I would list the names and make sure that each is closed properly.

```
for name in ftp.nlst():
  print(name)  # for debugging
  with  open(local_file_path + "/" + name, "wb") as f:
      ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + i, f.write)
```

Comment: I should of added that I have set the set_debuglevel(2), which will log every request sent to and from the server. I can see when the file is opened, but it never closes..

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line for this issue was the internet connection (download speed 1.45MB) and how the ftplib handles connection drops. When using *retrbinary* and the connection is dropped it is never resumed. The ftplib needs to support block mode ([RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt)), so if the connection is dropped it can resume starting at the latest block received.